# MS ACCESS : On a subject form, how can I highlight a required control IF AND ONLY IF the user misses it (an error is thrown)

Tags: database-design, ms-access, access-control, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I have built a subject form and would like to find a way to highlight a textbox control that is required (it is paired to a required field) IF AND ONLY IF the user fails to enter it. I know that there are validation rules that are built as part of the subject table that will give the user an indication of an error when they fail to enter required data. But, I am looking for a more "colorful" or "visual" indication, so to speak. I have seen people simply give a colorful border to a required field. This is fine, but I am trying to find a way to either highlight or make a colorful border on the required control IF AND ONLY IF an error is thrown.

I hope my question is clear. This is my first question on here so I apologize if it's messy. I am using ACCESS 2016

Comment: I can't understand your need. When exactly should the control be highlighted? Maybe enhance your question by a sample/workflow to make it clear?

Comment: I will add a work flow or something to better explain what I'm after.
Until I can put something better on here, hopefully this will suffice.

1. User opens subject form
2. User enters in data to various controls, but skips the REQUIRED control
3. User attempts to save the new record they made through the form
4. The REQUIRED control suddenly becomes highlighted in an error color to signify that the required control has not been filled.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *BeforeUpdate* event of the form, like:

```vb
Private Sub YourTextbox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim BackColor As Long
    
    Cancel = IsNull(Me!YourTextbox.Value)
    
    If Cancel = True Then
        BackColor = YourColourOfError
    Else
        BackColor = YourColourOfNoError
    End If
    Me!YourTextbox.BackColor = BackColor

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry this sounds so silly, but where exactly would I use this? A macro? In addition, I'm assuming "Me" is the form name?

Comment: Go to the textbox, select Properties, Events, BeforeUpdate. Select EventProcedure, click elipsis. Insert code in the sub function. `Me` _is_ the current form.

Comment: @Gustav : Didn’t you mean the BeforeUpdate event of the **form**?

Comment: @UnhandledException: No, I had the control itself in mind. But I have expanded the code to give better meaning and include the full function.

Comment: @Gustav: Hm, I expected you meant the forms event, because this would make sense, because he never edited the controls value in his described workflow...

Comment: @UnhandledException: Yes, if that could be the case, you would need that. But you would still need the control's code to reset the BackColor.

Comment: @Gustav: I agree. He needs both.